# Differential usage of Präsens and Perfekt

Tags: verb, tense, perfect-tense

So I've been trying to make sense of the differential usage of Präsens and Perfekt for cases which correspond to the English Present Perfect tenses (the regular one and the progressive one). As per my understanding, the rule of thumb is that one may use Präsens both for the usual Present Perfect and Present Perfect progressive (i.e., when the action/event is still ongoing in the present). However, one may use Perfekt only for the regular Present Perfect. Is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such scheme. In German, tenses are used completely different than in English.

German tenses come in pairs. The simple tense of each pair is for marking the non-past, and the perfect tense of each pair is for marking the past. There are seven such pairs, and they differ in the intent of speech they mark:

- Präsens / Perfekt — facts
- Präteritum / Plusquamperfekt — storytelling
- Futur I / Futur II — assumptions
- Konjunktiv I / Konjunktiv I Perfekt — hearsay
- Konjunktiv II / Konjunktiv II Perfekt — non-facts
- Konjunktiv I Futur I / Konjunktiv I Futur II — hearsay assumptions (seldom used)
- Konjunktiv II Futur I / Konjunktiv II Futur II — drop-in replacement for Konjunktiv II / Konjunktiv II Perfekt

(Futur II is a perfect tense.)

That system is very simple: You want to mark something as non-past and facts? – use Präsens. You want to mark it as past and facts?
— use Perfekt.

On top of that simple scheme, Northern speakers use Präteritum instead of Perfekt for the auxiliaries, the modals and some very common verbs. The more north you get, the more verbs belong to that group.

Comment: Even the distinction between present and future, which is very similar between English and German, is still different. English does sometimes put future events in the present tense: "We're leaving in five minute." but German carries this further to the point where the future tense is rare, at least when compared to English. As with many other aspects of language, a finite set of "rules" is only an approximation.

Comment: @RDBury very true. Yet I think one can consider this covered by the answer. Like "In 15 Minuten gehe ich einkaufen" is a statement about the future (facts) expressed in present tense. Yet when talking about the weather (assumption), I' still say "Morgen wird das Wetter sonnig" (instead of 'Morgen ist das Wetter sonnig' - though not completely unheard either, depending on how factual this is assumed, especially in the negative: "wird sonnig sagst Du? Ne, das regnet ab heute abend durch bis morgen abend")

Comment: I still firmly believe that this view of tenses is doing more harm than help to people new in the language. There is a reason German schools do not teach it like this.

Comment: The reason why they don't commonly teach it that way is inertia. You can't be admonished nor fired if you do it the same as everyone did it before.

Comment: Gotcha. Could you by any chance refer me to an academic source that teaches tenses in the manner you have mentioned? Want to learn more about this approach.